# Hibernate Envers performance MySQL

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, amazon-web-services, hibernate-envers

Right now I'm trying to choose the most appropriate approach in order to implement Audit Trail for my entities with AWS RDS MySQL database.

I have to log all entity changes including the initiator(user) who initiated these changes. One of the main criterion is performance.

Hibernate Envers looks like the easiest and the most complete solution and can be very quickly integrated. Right now I'm worried about the possible performance slowdown after Envers introducing. I saw a few posts where developers prefer approach for Audit Trail based on database triggers.

The main issue with triggers is how to get initiator(user) who initiated these changes.

Based on your experience, could you please suggest the approach for Java/Spring/Hibernate/MySQL(AWS) in order to implement Audit Trail for historical changes.

Also, do we have any solution for Audit Trail within AWS RDS MySQL database infrastructure ?

Comment: Can you elaborate on the performance issues or concerns you have?  I'm not aware of any performance issues but you're welcomed to outline those here or open a JIRA for me to take a look.

Comment: due to amount of requests I can quickly get very large tables with a historical changes. I afraid that it can slow down my system

Comment: That isn't an Envers performance problem, that's simply a side effect any auditing solution faces when you're needing to audit all changes in a high volume system scenario.  Whether you elect to use another solution or resort to database triggers, the volume of rows you generate remains constant given your business requirements.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Understand that speculation about performance without concrete evidence to support one's theory is analagous to premature optimization of code.  It's almost always a waste of time.

From a simple database point of view, as a table grows to a specific limit, yes it's performance will degrade, but typcally this mainly impacts queries and less on insertion/update if the table is properly indexed and queries properly formed.

But many databases support partitioning as a means to control performance concerns, particularly on larger tables.  This typically involves separating a table's data across a set of boundaries defined by a partition scheme you create.  You simply define what is the most relevant data and you try and store this partition on your fastest drives/storage and the less relevant, typically older, data is stored on your slower drives/storage.

You can also elect to store database tables in differing schemas/tablespaces by specifying the envers property `org.hibernate.envers.default_schema`.  If your database supports putting schemas in different database files on the file system, you can help increase performance by allowing your entity table reads/writes not impact the reads/writes of your audit tables.

I can't speak to MySQL's support for any of these things, but I do know that MSSQL/Oracle supports partitioning very easily and Oracle for sure allows the separation of schemas across differing database files.